# Is there a function in C++ that can get timestamps which cannot be changed? (internet independent)

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I am looking for a function that I can implement in a standalone C++ application to gather timestamps from a user's computer that they cannot change by modifying their system time. The goal is to enforce yearly subscriptions.

The application must be able to function internationally (so no standardized time zone), and cross-platform (so windows, IOS, Android, etc.) and the unique challenge here comes from needing this functionality regardless of whether the user ever connects to the internet past downloading the application.

Functionality within the C++ standard libraries would be preferred. Does anyone know if this is possible within C++ alone, or if there are functions in the Windows, IOS, Android, etc. libraries which provide this?

The users of my program are highly educated, and changing their system time/shutting off their system when not using the application to extend the life of this application is within their grasp.

Thanks

Comment: I do not believe anything like this exists in C++, or in any other language. If you own a computer, you can do anything to it. Thankfully.

Comment: Query a time server (requires internet) otherwise there's not much you can do

Comment: Nope.  It's **their** computer.

Comment: You are looking for digital signatures and trusted timestamps. You can use OpenSSL.

Anything "local" is not reliable and not trusted (and not legal in the EU, for example).

Comment: I really wouldn't worry about this.  Fritzing with the system clock on a modern computer is likely to cause trouble and sensible users won't do it.

Comment: @PaulSanders: That's why you have virtual machines.

Comment: @PaulSanders What's this "sensible user" you speak of?  ;-)

Comment: If the computer running your application is connected to the internet, you could access the [NIST Time Servers](https://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi).  In general, Users can't modify those time servers (and they are a basis for internet time).

Answer (score 4):

There is no such facility in the C++ Library, nor in any library I am aware of.  You actually can't do completely what you want: if the user switches off their computer and disconnects the battery from the real time clock, there is *no way* to tell if they have left the power off for five minutes or ten years.

The closest I can think of, is the Posix "monotonic clock".  That at least guarantees that it will never return an earlier time than it has previously returned (at least, without an intervening boot) - but there is nothing to stop a user running your application in a VM and stopping the clock when they shut down the app, and only restarting it when they start up again.  (Which means they get 24*365 hours of actually using your app - which will probably be spread over many years.)

In fact, if you can't connect to an external source of truth, there is nothing to stop the user resetting the VM to the state it was in when they had just installed the app.

You will have to tell your manager, it can't be done.

Comment: Doesn't a monotonic clock only work in a single boot?  AFAIK there is nothing stopping a monotonic clock from returning the same value every time the system starts.

Comment: [POSIX also states](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) "the absolute value of the `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` clock is meaningless".  It's only useful for determining how much time has passed since a previous check of that same clock under the same circumstances that the platform documents it being monotonic.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - but that is probably good enough for the OP.  1.  Save the value at installation or subscription update.  2.  Read the value at some interval - if it more than "saved_value + 1 year", refuse to continue running.

Comment: @MartinBonner That's still limited to a system that defines the "unspecified point in the past" in a way that would work. (I'm ignoring the fact that monotonic clocks are optional - most systems do have one, also the application in question can be delivered only for systems that do have a monotonic clock.)  Still, defeating such usage is likely trivial. Even checking an external source is likely not very hard to defeat.

Comment: @IgorG [Bangs head against desk] Have I managed to get it right *this* time?

Comment: @MartinBonner, absolutely! Great!

Comment: All I have to add is that if your application records the local time at regular intervals as it runs then it can detect that the user has tried to reset the local time between runs. On the other hand, if they can determine where you have stashed that value, then they could probably back-up and restore that file as well. You could stash the value in the spare bytes at the end of the last block holding your executable or data files, so the value does not appear inside your file, but a quick probe with strace will show you doing the direct disk access.